Counting no. of solution of 2 linear equations modulo prime?
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p = \{ 0, 1, .. p-1 \}$ for some prime $p$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then given $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ where $a_1 \neq a_2$ and $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ what is the number of solutions of $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^n$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, satisfying
\begin{align}
\vec{x} \cdot \vec{a_1} + y \equiv b_1 \mod p \\
\vec{x} \cdot \vec{a_2} + y \equiv b_2 \mod p
\end{align}
is given by? The question in my Algorithms book actually requires us to show that the number of such solutions is the same for all values of $b_1$ and $b_2$, so I thought counting the number of solutions might be the way to go.
My attempt: I feel the result is false - for if $a_1$ and $a_2$ differ in exactly 1 coordinate, it seems to me that there should be no solution possible unless $b_1 = b_2$, which would contradict the book's result.
